# Equivalent to += (plus equal) to add scopes with ActiveRecord in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I would like to chain my scopes according to conditions. But because of lazy evaluation of scopes in ActiveRecord only the last assignement is taking into account.

```
@list = Product.all
if condition 1
  @list = Product.scope1
if condition 2
 @list = Product.scope2
if condition 3
  @list = Product.scope3
...
@list
```

I would like to be able to accumulate scopes one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain them like this

```
@list = Product.all
@list = @list.scope1 if condition1
@list = @list.scope2 if condition2
@list
```

Then in the end `@list` holds the elements you want.

Comment: Thank you ! It seems so obvious now that I have the answer.